# It wants me to put : but i dont know how and where

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

i have this little statement in my code

```
if timesdone == 0:
    m.downloadfile()
    timesdone = timesdone + 1
```

but when i want to run the file it says      ':' expected

the whole code is

```
from urllib import request
from lxml import etree
import main as m
timesdone = 0
def get_youtube_title(youtube_id):
    youtube_watch_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyJRyif6_kk'
    youtube_watch_url += youtube_id
    youtube = etree.HTML(request.urlopen(youtube_watch_url).read().decode('utf-8'))
    return youtube.xpath("//title")[0].text if len(youtube.xpath("//title")) > 0 else "NO Title"
finalyoutubetitle = (get_youtube_title('2wEA8nuThj8'))
print ("title ="+finalyoutubetitle)


if timesdone = 0(
    m.downloadfile()
    timesdone = timesdone + 1
)
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: the syntax of an if statement in python needs you to add an ":" after the conditional declaration

Comment: you should also ask your questions as an actual question. your title doesn't say what "it" means and it's way too broad. you should also demonstrate what you've tried to do to solve the problem, and that you have researched ways to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Check the edited question.

```
if timesdone == 0:
    m.downloadfile()
    timesdone = timesdone + 1
```